# Xcode/iPhone Development 6 months in - Annoyances

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've been iPhone programming for 6 months and come from a PC/Java/Eclipse background and still have a few annoyances with Xcode/iPhone programming I wonder are there any shortcuts to.

1. Is there any way to prevent multiple windows opening all the time in XCode?
   a) When you click on the Errors/Warnings in the bottom right of the status bar build errors are shown in separate window. Any way to get these to show in the main editor?
   b) Anyway to get debugger to appear in main editor.
   I have a big screen iMac and it's still window hell on Macs.
   When you come from Alt-Tab the Mac is a nightmare.

2) Anyway to get a toolbar item on the main editor to:
a) Open Console (I know CMD-thingy-R)
b) Open Break points (you have to open Debugger first then breakpoints)
I know there's keyboard shortcuts but I have only left hand free others on the trackball so any keys on right hand side of keyboard are too far.

I know you can add Finder toolbar scripts (just wondering if anyway to extend Xcode).
Are there utilities to extend Xcode? Scripts/Automator/Any Services I can setup to help.
Can you automate Xcode like you can with Windows/ActiveX/VBA

3) Limit lookups using CMD + double click.
If I double click on a variable to find its definition using CMD + double click it shows every occurrence of all variables with that name. (annoying it you name all you maps mapView)
Anyway to get it to limit to the current class or at least order so current class is first.

4) Find doesn't seem to loop backwards if result all above cursor position
I'm in a class and I hit CMD + F for find.
Find box appears.
I enter some text hit return.
It says I have x matches but only back arrow is highlight in Find
But when I hit < it does nothing.
I need to scroll to the top and redo the search.
If the text is both forwards and backwards then both < > are highlighted and it works.
is this a bug or a 'feature'

Missing Eclipse features
I have been looking at the User Script menu but was wondering how powerful they are?
5) any scripts around to generate source from members such as description: @property @synthesize
if I add a new member, run a script will generate @property/@syntesize and release in dealloc
7) any good sites for scripts?

7. SCM
   Im having problems with SCM and Folders on HD under project Classes directory.
   You get a library e.g. JSON. It usually comes as a folder. You copy it to the /Classes for your project. /Classes/JSON
   I create a Group for the Library in Xcode under Classes group.
   Classes
   JSON
   I drag the files from the folder into xcode into the JSON Group.
   I add them to the SCM and icon changes from ? to A
   but if I try and commit them it say folder /JSON is not under SCM.
   Can you drag a folder into Xcode so that it AND its files get included in SCM?
8. Anyway to stop Xcode Help from being on top all the time. 
   I keep feeling like punching it and telling it to get out of the way! :)
   I dont mind it open just not in the way once I've finished. 
   Yes I know I can Ctrl-W

Sites: the main site I use to learn Obj-C are :
stackoverflow.com
Google code Search - tonnes of full apps on here
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/
Apple Developers Forums (anyway to get RSS feed to these or is that blasphemy :) )
Safari - 100s of IT book though prob too many to keep up :)
any others?
Any site that gives simple examples for Obj-C/ UIKit
The docs just show the methods but actual examples (Google code search has helped a lot here)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the behavior in question 4 under Xcode 3.2.1 under OS X 10.6.3. If all matches are above the cursor position the window is scrolled up to the top match (highlighted in yellow) and all other matches are highlighted in grey. Forward and back buttons work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**--> 1):**

In `Xcode -> Preferences -> General`, select *"All-In-One"* for the Layout.

I was used to have only one window and found this mode much better than the default.

Comment: excellent..its commented out if any windows open. prob why i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

[Generating @property and @synthesize code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151393/xcode-script-for-generating-synthesizing-properties).