# Is there a shortcut for adding properties in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, xcode4

In Visual Studio if I type `prop` and press tab then a property is created for me, I just have to fill in the details. Is there anything like this in Xcode 4?

I realise that a similar question has been asked here: [Xcode script for generating/synthesizing properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151393/xcode-script-for-generating-synthesizing-properties) but it seems to relate to Xcode 3 judging by the date.

Thanks, Gareth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode4 you can add a property, create an ivar, get release calls in dealloc and setting to nil in viewDidUnload all by simply dragging a UI component from within the XIB editor into your view controller's header file. All you have to do is name the property and Xcode4 does the rest for you. Nice!

Unfortunately if you just want to manually add a property, create an associated ivar and manage memory in an arbitrary class, there is no way to do that. At least none I have found so far! The smart code completion undeniably is an improvement but not the same as an intelligent operation to add all the boiler-plate for the addition of a property.

Comment: Awesome. Unfortunately it works on properties that are outlet :). You can't do that for normal properties unless you pretend it's an outlet first.

Comment: Note that this didn't work for me until I realized you need to drag from the referencing outlets section (or pop-over) to the header. (As opposed to dragging the actual UI component. See http://programmaremobile.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/xcode-4-tip-automatically-make-iboutlet.html.

Answer (score 1):

The code completion in Xcode 4 has been greatly improved.  Just start typing @prop... and complete the in the header file.  THen switch to your implementation file and start type @syn... and you are done.

Comment: Is this as good as it gets? I presume I still have to release my property in the dealloc method.

Comment: Yea, it would be nice if there was a shortcut similar to the UI drag/drop that created all of the same code snipets.

Comment: Now you can use ARC and skip releases altogether.